# How can I properly send images (and text) from React to Django API using fetch?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, django, fetch, django-registration

My django API views is setup as follows;

```
class AddProductToStorageAPIView(APIView):
    parser_classes = [MultiPartParser, FormParser]

    def post(self, request, format=None):
        print(request.data) #I want to know what data is coming in for now
        return Response({"details": "all done successfully"}, status=200)
```

When I make a POST request from postman (with formdata), the data `request.data` returns:

```
<QueryDict: {'title': ['Something'], 'description': ['some description'], 'price': ['600'], 'category': ['A'], 'Images': [<InMemoryUploadedFile: img-transparent_bg.jpg (image/jpeg)>]}>
```

However, when I try to make a POST request from the react side. Things got so messed up. First here is my code in react side:

```
const handleSubmit = (e) =>{
        e.preventDefault();
        var headers = new Headers();
        headers.append("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");
        headers.append("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken)

        var formdata = new FormData();
        formdata.append("title", state.title);
        formdata.append("description", state.description);
        formdata.append("price", state.price);
        formdata.append("category", state.category);
        for (var i = fileinput.current.files.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            formdata.append("Images", fileinput.current.files[0], 
            fileinput.current.files[0].name);
        }//because the file input has 'multiple'='true' (i.e multiple files can be added)
        
        var requestOptions = {
          method: 'POST',
          headers: headers,
          body: formdata,
          redirect: 'follow'
        };

        fetch("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/plus/product/", requestOptions)
          .then(response => response.text())
          .then(result => console.log(result))
          .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
    }
```

On submit however, I get `400 bad request` error saying `multipart form parse error - invalid boundary in multipart:None` and I don't have a clue what that means.

Then, I changed `headers.append("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");` above to      `headers.append("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;; boundary=--------------------------426310166704307097870742")` which is something I copied from postman (I don't know what I did here too). So when I submit again, the no boundary error disappears but I get this freaking numbers and symbols on my terminal and I have no idea what it means. It looks like this;

```
<QueryDict: {'title': ['So \r\n------WebKitFormBoundarydLnO3cP4KrAwpSAA\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="description"\r\n\r\nThis is them\r\n------WebKitFormBoundarydLnO3cP4KrAwpSAA\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="price"\r\n\r\n120\r\n------WebKitFormBoundarydLnO3cP4KrAwpSAA\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="category"\r\n\r\nShirt\r\n------WebKitFormBoundarydLnO3cP4KrAwpSAA\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="Images"; filename="profile-transparent_bg.jpg"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n����\x00\x10JFIF\x00\x01\x01\x01\x00`\x00`\x00\x00��\x00C\x00\x03\x02\x02\x03\x02\x02\x03\x03\x03\x03\x04\x03\x03\x04\x05\x08\x05\x05\x04\x04\x05\n\x07\x07\x06\x08\x0c\n\x0c\x0c\x0b\n\x0b\x0b\r\x0e\x12\x10\r\x0e\x11\x0e\x0b\x0b\x10\x16\x10\x11\x13\x14\x15\x15\x15\x0c\x0f\x17\x18\x16\x14\x18\x12\x14\x15\x14��\x00C\x01\x03\x04\x04\x05\x04\x05\t\x05\x05\t\x14\r\x0b\r\x14\x14\x14\x14\x14\x14\x14\x14\x14\x14\x14\x14\x14\x14\x14\x14\x14\x14\x14\x14\x14\x14\x14\x14\x14\x14\x14\x14\x14\x14\x14\x14\x14\x14\x14\x14\x14\x14\x14\x14\x14\x14\x14\x14\x14\x14\x14\x14\x14\x14��\x00\x11\x08\x01�\x01�\x03\x01"\x00\x02\x11\x01\x03\x11\x01��\x00\x1f\x00\x00\x01\x05\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x02\x03\x04\x05\x06\x07\x08\t\n\x0b��\x00�\x10\x00\x02\x01\x03\x03\x02\x04\x03\x05\x05\x04\x04\x00\x00\x01}\x01\x02\x03\x00\x04\x11\x05\x12!1A\x06\x13Qa\x07"q\x142���\x08#B��\x15R��$3br�\t\n\x16\x17\x18\x19\x1a%&\'()*456789:CDEFGHIJSTUVWXYZcdefghijstuvwxyz���������������������������������������������������������������������������\x00\x1f\x01\x00\x03\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x02\x03\x04\x05\x06\x07\x08\t\n\x0b��\x00�\x11\x00\x02\x01\x02\x04\x04\x03\x04\x07\x05\x04\x04\x00\x01\x02w\x00\x01\x02\x03\x11\x04\x05!1\x06\x12AQ\x07aq\x13"2�\x08\x14B����\t#3R�\x15br�\n\x16$4�%�\x17\x18\x19\x1a&\'()*56789:CDEFGHIJSTUVWXYZcdefghijstuvwxyz��������������������������������������������������������������������������\x00\x0c\x03\x01\x00\x02\x11\x03\x11\x00?\x00�N�(����(\x00��(\x00��(\x00��(\x00��(\x00��(\x00��(\x00���/����\x07��\x1b�V��u]6M\x12�L�cty?��5��%\x14��m�(m\x14��m�\x06�K���\x00�(��\n(����\x1e���]�v�H\\��3@\x1f:~տ\x10\r�\x10����@����e��$�e�[�\x0f�o\x17_�3�V���W\x10��w!��݊�\x1a���� ^*���\x1a�2\x13+�\x1f?�$h���0)�QHaE\x14P\x07��\r\n------WebKitFormBoundarydLnO3cP4KrAwpSAA--\r\n']}>
```

Somebody please help me. All I want to do is to send images (could be more than one) and some texts from the react frontend to my Django API.